# How to get FLAC frame length

Tags: frame, decode, flac

I'm study FLAC decode problem, but can't figure out how to get FLAC frame length. Please help.
https://xiph.org/flac/format.html
I docoded METADATA_BLOCK_STREAMINFO, and get below data:

```
mMinBlock: 4096
mMaxBlock: 4096
mMinFrame: 1201
mMaxFrame: 12804
mSampleRate: 44100
mBitPerSample: 16
mTotalSample: 14170212
```

Then I start to analyse first Frame, below is the info from first Frame header:

```
isFixBlock = true
blockSize = 12
sampleRate = 9
channel = 10
sampleSize = 4
number = 0
Blocking strategy is fixed-blocksize;
Block size: 1100, it means 256 * (2^(12-8)) samples = 4096 samples;
Sample rate: 1001 : 44.1kHz;
Channel: 2;
Sample size: 100 : 16 bits per sample;
```

So from above infomation, we'll know this frame has 4096 samples, and sample size is 16 bits per sample. That means this frame length is at least(ignore subframe header and frame footer,etc.) 4096 * 16 / 8 = 8192 bytes. But if I check the FLAC file manually, the offset gap of first and second frame is only 2976 bytes, this means the frame length of first frame is only 2976 bytes. Is there anything wrong for my calculation?

My purpose is get frame offset and frame length of every frame, is there any good way? I know there is sync code 0xFF F8, but it's very low efficiency. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

From http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/flac-dev/2016-February/005845.html

> The frame length you calculated (8192 bytes) is that of the decoded 
>   frame, not of the FLAC frame. As it is compressed, it should be indeed 
>   smaller than 8192 bytes.
>
> There is no direct way to find the frame length except finding where the 
>   next frame starts.